# Obtaining the start time when a web browser begins to load AND obtaining the start time of an HTTP request of a resource

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

As I have been googling around I have seen many posts on other websites of people asking this question with no solution

I am trying to figure out how long it's taking my web server running NGINX 
to receive a request from the browser, the server itself once it says it receives a particular http request reports in its logs mere 6MS to complete it, however from the browser its taking 11+ seconds. I need to measure the time between when an HTTP request was made to server and the time it took for the server to receive the request to solve my issue.

There is nowhere in the google chrome developer tools that can tell me a timestamp when a website started to load - each subsequent HTTP request says how many seconds or milliseconds since the page load began, takes place. If I know when the page began to load I can do the math manually to figure out the timestamp of my API request using the devtools waterfall.

Answer (score 1):

there is a chrome API that can be used in the developer tools console:

To obtain the web pages browser load start time in the console you can run

```
performance.timeOrigin
// => 1551815483060.8398
```

to convert this value to a readable timestamp:

```
new Date(performance.timeOrigin).toUTCString()
// => "Tue, 05 Mar 2019 19:51:23 GMT"
```

next, you will need to get the startTime of the loaded resource, to see all the resources that got loaded the following command will work list them out in the console

```
performance.getEntriesByType('resource')
// => []
```

(will return an array of loaded resources), that array will not be blank like the one I listed, it will have a property of `startTime` with the MS since the page load began

```
performance.getEntriesByType('resource')[5].startTime
// => 2820.3300000022864
```

You can then add those two values together to get the official date stamp when the browser began its request to your server

```
new Date(performance.timeOrigin + performance.getEntriesByType('resource')[5].startTime).toUTCString()
// => "Tue, 05 Mar 2019 19:51:25 GMT"
```

[for details on the performance interface, see the following docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin)